# Asp.net Web api core 2 and Swagger when adding [Routing] attribute, Response Content Type '*/XML' disappears

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-2.0

I am using Asp.net web.api core 2.0 and Swashbuckle 1.1.0.
Input and ouput XmlSerializer has been added.

When I add [Route] attribute to an action, swagger UI Response content type 'text/xml' or 'application/xml' is removed from the option list.

Any ideas why this is occuring?

```
[HttpGet("....")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(..)

[HttpGet]
[Route("ByFilter")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetByFilter(...)
```

Regards
Floyd

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something is buggy on this Swagger version. As workaround you could use the attribute specifying the return type of the end-point.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("ByFilter")]
[Produces("application/xml")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetByFilter(...)
```